# Getting Py4J error on pyspark reducyByKey (beginner)

Tags: pyspark

I am new to pyspark and trying to follow some basic examples.

The following reduceByKey code produces an error and I have no idea why

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()                                 #ok
rdd = sc.parallelize([("foo",1),("foo",1),("bar",2)])           #ok
rdd2 = rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y).collect()               #error
```

raises:

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Constructor org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD([class org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionRDD, class org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonFunction, class java.lang.Boolean]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:179)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:196)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:237)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am using:

Spark 3.0.0

Python   3.7.4

pyspark  2.3.2

py4j-0.10.7

Comment: i have `pyspark 3.0.1` and it does not give me any error

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing to:

Spark 2.4.7

pyspark 2.4.7